# Using Django web application to be submitted as a project

Tags: django, web-applications, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have my main project created in Django as a web application, I have completed my coding. So now that I have to submit the project and have to present it. Is there any way I can render it as an application so that my tutor could just click on an icon or link and just directly open the application instead of starting a server and multiple other things before using the app. Any advice that would help the application to dodge this complicated process would be much appreciated.

I even tried looking up information on this but couldn't find anything ueful.

Answer (score 0):

There are websites that provide free web hosting, you could upload your code there and upload the database and once you have that set up just get the url link to it and give it to the person you want.

I remember using https://www.awardspace.com/ for my school web projects. it could help you.

Theres is no way I know of that you could just render and get an .exe file to just click and install and run.